# Why does my Leaflet map centered the point of its lower left coner?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, leaflet

I have a leaflet map on my website with markers. However, I can't centered it well on Paris.
This code works :

```
map.setView([lat,lng],zoom);
```

The map shows Paris as it's supposed to but the point I chose is not in the middle of my map. The map is centered on its lower left corner

Does someone know how to center the point in the middle of my map?

Thank's

Edit : full code

```
 var map = L.map('map', {
    scrollWheelZoom: false
})
map.setView(<?php echo "[".$latVille.", ".$lngVille."], ".$zoomVille;?>);
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v8',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: ''
}).addTo(map);
Array.from($(".js-marker")).forEach((item) => {
        let marker = L.popup({
                                autoClose: false,
                                closeOnEsacapeKey: false,
                                closeOnClick: false,
                                closeButton: false,
                                className: 'marker',
                                maxWidth: 300
                            })
                                .setLatLng([item.dataset.lat,item.dataset.lng])
                                .setContent(item.dataset.prix+' €')
                                .openOn(map);})
```

Result : [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank's JulesUK for you're comment. I edited my question with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best way to do it but I used `setView` after setting the markers and it works !

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding markers it may be because of that, set the view after the markers are added, but hard to tell without the code.

I use for the tiles and this code will centre on the point

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'Your token';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
  .setView([52.462610, -1.588580], 14)
  .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'));
```